# How to add image over whole screen

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, uiimageview

I am trying to put overlay image over whole iPhone screen (over **navigation** and **tabbar** also) from `viewDidLoad` but nothing happens.

```
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]
                              initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"overlayimage.png"]];
UIWindow* window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    [window.rootViewController.view addSubview: imageView];

UITapGestureRecognizer * recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    recognizer.delegate = self;
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled =  YES;
    self.imageView = imageView;
```

This is the result that I am trying to get:
[image]

Comment: If you want to have a splash screen, you need to create new UIViewControoler

Comment: Yes I have splash screen. But still can't add image over whole screen.

Comment: Then why you doesnt use UIIMagePicerViewController ?

Comment: @iPatel why you remove answer I have just wanted to accept it?

Comment: @1110- is my answer help in your case ? other wise use UIImagePickerViewController :)]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `UIWindow` is a subclass of `UIView`, you can also add subviews to the key window.
These subviews will appear above any view controller.

```
UIWindow *keyWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
[keyWindow addSubview:imageView];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
imageView.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview: imageView];
```